# Error saving a screenshot twice instead of once

Tags: ios, swift

My hope is to save a screenshot successfully, but until now, my code is saving the screen twice and I do not know why.

I have the following:

```
class finalPostal: UIViewController{

    var gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()


  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "screenShotMethod")

        gesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.5

        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }


   func screenShotMethod() {


        let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)

        let alertSaved = UIAlertController(title: "Caputra guardada", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alertSaved.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(self.gesture)

        }))

        presentViewController(alertSaved, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code

Comment: How long are you long pressing for. It may get called multiple times depending on the duration of the press

Comment: put a breakpoint on code to see if that method gets hit twice. If yes, use bool variable to avoid multiple hits

Comment: You could create a function to make sure it hasn't been called to often.

Comment: I've tried to change the duration to 3 secs but it's still wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the state of gesture and take the screenshot only when the state is equals to

> UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

In your screenShotMethod method